# Android Hello world project not running

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run a simple Android application (Hello, world!) in `Eclipse Indigo`. The application is programmed correctly. When I run project, `AVD` will start, but the application won't. I have installed the `ADT` and the `SDK`. `Logcat` and Console are OK (no errors messages).

EDIT: Solved, I changed the value of SD card.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds dumb but you have to wait, sometimes a really long time, for the virtual device to load.  It's generally slow to respond to inputs and choppy to run as well; you will get different results on the emulator vs. on a real phone sometimes.  Just the nature of virtualization really.

It's generally crappy to develop on the AVD, everyone I know who develops Android just uses their own real hardware.  There are some official developer hardware units you could look into but I've been more than satisfied with a standard android phone connected by USB.

If you are saying the AVD is loaded and the app isn't starting check in the virtual device's app panel, it may not be starting on "install" because of the virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a virtual device first... or to connect your phone